# Getting address of parent in derived initialization list

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, initialization-list

Is there a standard-and-safe way of getting the address of one of the base classes in the child constructor initialization list?

Here is what I want to do:

I have a multiple classes which provides some functionality to process buffers (void*, length), and I have multiple classes which holds data (c-style structures). I want to provide both combined to the user with minimal code. Here is what I think about:

```
//Parent1 is POD (old c-style structure)
struct Parent1{/*C style stuff*/};

//Parent2 and Parent3 are NOT POD (virtual functions, copy constructors, ...)
class Parent2{public: Parent2(void*, size_t);/*stuff*/};
class Parent3{public: Parent3(void*, size_t);/*stuff*/};

/*order of inhertiance is not guranteed, it could be Parent2, Parent2, Parent3*/
struct Child1 : public Parent1, public Parent2, public Parent3
{
    Child1()
        : Parent2((Parent1*)this, sizeof(Parent1)),
        Parent3((Parent1*)this, sizeof(Parent1))
    {
    }

    //using self() instead of this is trick which I don't prefer to use.
    const Child1* self()const{return this;}
};
```

This compiles fine of gcc but gives warning on visual studio, I will try other embedded compilers later. I am searching for a standard   solution which can pass [MISRA C++ checks](http://www.misra-cpp.com), [polyspace](http://www.mathworks.com/products/polyspace) checks and [any other static analysis tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B).

**EDIT**:

Visual studio warning: warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list

Comment: Would making `Parent1` a member and providing `operator Parent1&()` and `operator Parent1 const&() const` be an option? Then you could just pass a pointer to that member object, which hopefully wouldn't trigger the warning.

Comment: @celtschk but this is a composition solution, not inheritance. which means I have to rewrite all Parent2 and Parent3 public function.

Comment: Why would you have to rewrite `Parent2` and `Parent3`? The only way those know about `Parent1` is through the pointer passed in the constructor, right?

Answer (score 0):

In the ctor list the usual conversions work, so Derived* converts to Base* implicitly. Without any kind of work. (Provided this kind of conversion was required by the called function or ctor; for void* you get a reinterpret_cast equivalent).

However you must be aware of lifetime issues. During construction the class is half-inited, so using this or any of its converted forms may lead to using parts that will be initialized later.  That's why you get the warning. To your case it may or may not apply.

I usually not allow anything but store the pointer passed from `this`, and actual use will come later.

Don't use c-style casts in place of static_cast! And your taking void* smells badly, consider taking typed pointer and scrap all casts, leaving just implicit conversions. 
Especially as no facility is seen to recover the lost type info.

Comment: Note that he passes the pointer to `void*` arguments, so the compiler cannot possibly know that `Child1*` shall not be converted directly to `void*`, but first to `Parent1*` which might include a pointer adjustment. Also, since he converts to a POD base class which at that point is already initialized, the only way to access uninitialized data would be an explicit conversion back to the derived type, which by itself would be a bad idea (and given that there's a further implicit conversion to `void*` involved, is also quite obviously not intended).

Comment: Why you think I did not note that? Actually in first unposted version it was that way, that was corrected to use static_cast instead of scrapping.

Comment: Because you wrote "In the ctor list the usual conversions work, so Derived* converts to Base* implicitly." This is decidedly *not* true if you initialize a `void*` with the pointer (which is the only thing he did with the pointer in the initializer list).